# Using Interceptor to add logging to GenServer

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming, gen-server

I am currently trying to add logging capabilities to [GenServers](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html). I am aware that there are existing solutions that provide insights into a GenServer's behavior, including logging, but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking to implement a solution myself, one I can afterwards customize and expand upon (e.g. instead of logging make API calls). For this purpose, I found the [Interceptor library](https://hexdocs.pm/interceptor/Interceptor.html). This seems great for what I want to do as it allows for some custom code could be executed before/after/... a specified function each time it is executed.

What I did until now is the following. First, I made my own module called `GenServerViz`. In this module I basically copied all of the regular [GenServer code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/main/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex) I found on GitHub, but then expanded it with the Interceptor library. I then `use` `GenServerViz` instead of the regular `GenServer`. Using this approach I was able to intercept all functions that are explicitly defined in GenServers, such as `start`, `start_link`, `stop`, `call`, `cast`, etc. However, I am currently clueless how I would go about intercepting the callbacks such as `handle_cast`, `handle_call`, `init`, etc as these functions are not explicitly defined in GenServers but are usually defined in the user modules themselves.

The 'ugly' solution would be to setup the interception for each module that makes use of my `GenServerViz`. This would include adding import statements, setting up configuration and either annotating or wrapping the relevant functions inside an intercept block. This would be a very cumbersome process on a bigger scale. It would also mean that one cannot easily switch from the regular `GenServer` to `GenServerViz` by just changing the use/import statements in existing projects, something I would like to be easily possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/could-i-leverage-elixir-s-metaprogramming-capabilities-to-automatically-annotate-all-functions-with-a-given-name/52020

Answer (score 1):

If your use case for this should be: *because I want to learn what's going on*, consider using the [GenServer debugging options](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html#module-debugging-with-the-sys-module)  like `debug: [:trace]`:

```
{:ok, pid } = GenServer.start_link(MyModule, init_arg, [debug: [:trace]])
```

This will print debug messages to stdio. So no real Logging but it's quite informative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know there are existing solutions, however, I would like to come up with my own (customizable) soluition. My goal is not purely to gain an insight, but to use this as a first step for a bigger project down the line. One where I will need to hook into the described GenSererver behavior.